# Please Prove this question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x,y,z$ are all different real numbers, then
$$\dfrac{1}{(x-y)^2} + \dfrac{1}{(y-z)^2} +\dfrac{1}{(z-x)^2} = \left(\dfrac{1}{x-y} +\dfrac{1}{y-z} +\dfrac{1}{z-x}\right)^2.$$

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but I doubt that it's true. I suggest visiting https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for tips on effective formatting.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624921

Answer (score 5):

Let $\displaystyle\;a = \frac{1}{x-y}, b = \frac{1}{y-z}, c = \frac{1}{z-x}\;$, then RHS - LHS
equals to
$$(a+b+c)^2 - (a^2+b^2+c^2) = 2(ab+bc+ca) = 2abc(\frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c)$$
Since $\displaystyle\;\frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c = (x-y)+(y-z)+(z-x) = 0\;$, we have RHS = LHS.